# Using jquery in google apps script

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-apps-script

I want to use jquery to create an application using google apps scripts. But i got failed.

below is a example of what I am using. A basic one.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js">             
</script>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#Hide').click(hideMe);
  });

  function hideMe(){
    this.value = 'Clicked!';
  }
  </script>

</head>
<body>
<input type="button" name="Hide" id="Hide" value="Hide me" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry I was using incompatible library. Latest library to use to use jquery in google apps script. https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js

Comment: Did you see my answer?

Answer (score -1):

Here is a [working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/michelem09/vuhvaczo/1) of what you are trying to do:

HTML:

```
<input type="button" name="Hide" id="Hide" value="Hide me" />
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#Hide').click(function () {
        $(this).val('Clicked');
    });
});
```

Of course it can work also as this, it's the same:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#Hide').click(hideme);

    function hideme () {
        $(this).val('Clicked');
    }
});
```

Comment: this doesnt explain what was wrong with the op code